# No puedo acceder a un campo de la respuesta, quiero acceder al campo estado para usarlo en el if,

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Por favor intento acceder al campo estado que viene de mi tabla de usuarios para pasarle un parámetro en el `IF`, pero al ponerle `response.estado` me da el mensaje de error

En la variable response llamo al método que me trae como resultado un usuario, luego a esta variable que contiene el objeto intento acceder a un campo especifico este es el resultado de la variable response

```
[
    {
        "cedulausuario": "xxxxxx",
        "nombreusuario": "Crisxx",
        "apellidousuario": "Xxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
        "password": "12345",
        "estado": 1,
        "fechacreacion": null,
        "tipousuario": 1
    }
]
```

quiero acceder al campo estado

```
async function UpdateUserStatus(req, res) {
   const cedulausuario = req.params.cedulausuario
   try {
      const response = await user.Get_User_ById(cedulausuario)
      if (response!='' && response.estado== '1') {
         await user.Update_Status_User(cedulausuario)
         res.status(200).send({ mensaje:'OK', estado: 'Usuario activado'})
      } else {
         res.status(200).send({mensaje:'Error', estado: 'El usuario ya esta activo o no existe'}) 
      }
   }
   catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(500).send({ mensaje: e.Smessage })
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Me causa un poco de extrañeza que, si bien tu método *Get_User_ById* debería devolverte un usuario en un **objeto**, lo esta haciendo en un **arreglo**.

Fuera de eso, como `response` es un arreglo, debes acceder a sus propiedades indicándole el índice, de esta forma

```
response[0].estado
```

Simplemente eso. Te sugiero de todas maneras revisar tu método para que te retorne lo que corresponde :)

Nos comentas si tienes dudas.

Comment: Si me accedio de esa manera, pero como puedo hacer para que me devuelba un objero json y no un arreglo, y muchas gracias

Comment: Es que para eso deberías crear otra pregunta e incluir en ella como estas implementando el método _Get_User_ById_. Considera también, marcar la respuesta como correcta si te fue de utilidad. Puedes tomar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que revises como funciona el foro :)

Comment: primer error, esto no es un foro :)